# Outputting values into csvs - command line

Tags: bash, csv, command-line

New to this site and programming in general (biologist by background).

Anyways, I have a task which is to obtain a text files name, count unique lines, count total lines and output this into a csv file. This is the code I am using in Cygwin

```
#!/bin/bash
file=./data/*.txt
name= ls ./data > output.csv
unique= sort $file | uniq | wc -l >> output.csv
total= cat $file | wc -l >> output.csv
nano output.csv
```

I get all the correct outputs, my questions are:

1. Can I choose in which column each value is entered? At the moment they are added directly underneath each other.
2. Is there a more efficient way of adding the outputs to the output file?

Thank you!

Fran

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I'm a pretty casual user so still don't have enough to upvote. Rest assured I will soon :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous improvements to make to the existing code, which is:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=./data/*.txt
name= ls ./data > output.csv
unique= sort $file | uniq | wc -l >> output.csv
total= cat $file | wc -l >> output.csv
nano output.csv
```

The three lines that write to `output.csv` carefully set environment variables `name`, `unique` and `total` to empty strings and then run commands — which isn't precisely wrong, but really isn't what you had in mind, either.  The `sort | uniq` can be simplified to `sort -u`.  There's no need for the `cat $file | wc -l` when `wc -l < $file` will do the same job with one fewer processes.  The `ls` line is generating the same names as the wild card expansion does.  You've got some issues with one file at a time vs all files together, too.

If you want a CSV file with name, unique lines, and total lines for each file, then we'd expect to see a loop in the code.

```
for file in ./data/*.txt
do
    unique=$(sort -u $file | wc -l)
    total=$(wc -l < $file)
    echo "$file,$unique,$total"
done
```

This runs `sort -u` to sort uniquely (no need for the explicit `uniq`), and captures the output from `wc -l`.  It runs `wc -l` with its standard input from the file for the total line count; using the I/O redirection stops `wc` from printing the file name.  The echo then prints the data.  If you only want the base name of the file (just `xyz.txt` and not `./data/xyz.txt`), then you can fix that in the `echo`:

```
echo "$(basename $file),$unique,$total"
```

or:

```
echo "${file##*/},$unique,$total"
```

The only possible downside to this is that it runs the commands once per file, which could be a bit of a problem if there are lots of files.  However, this will work — get it right first, and only then, if there is a speed problem, spend time on optimizing it.

Comment: Thanks for that, you're completely right about the variable names. I was modifying an incomplete block of code where the output was
`echo $v1, $v2, $v3`
and forgot that they were no longer needed when changed to outputting as a file. 


I found the cat was necessary to remove the wc adding the path (which I did not want). 


In this case, the folder containing the file only contains a single file so I don't need the for loop, but the next exercise was for multiple files in a folder and I used something similar to what you described. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Nobody can compete with Jonathan Leffler, but the following gawk script also handles your requirements.  It's a little more code, but in cases with multiple files, it may work more efficiently than a shell script.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f

function show() {
  print last,length(unique),total;
  last=FILENAME;
  delete(unique);
  total=0;
}

BEGIN {
  OFS=",";
}

NR==1 {
  last=FILENAME;
}

FILENAME != last {
  show();
}

{
  total++; unique[$0];
}

END {
  show();
}
```

The only novel thing here is the use of the `unique[]` array.  Since awk's arrays are all associative, using `$0` as a key makes an array whose length is the number of unique lines.  And merely making reference to an array element causes it to exist, so you don't actually need to *set* `unique[$0]` to anything.

To use the script, you'd use a command line like the following:

```
$ ./script.sh one.txt two.txt > output.csv
```

Or alternately something like

```
$ ./script.sh *.txt > output.csv
```

Note that in Cygwin, you may need to install the `gawk` package explicitly, and you will need to adjust the path to gawk in the first line of the script.  You can type `which gawk` to see if it is already installed, and if so, where it lives on your system.